# Animate width WPF left sided

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, wpf-animation

I have a `Grid`which I'm able to animate the following way:

[image: Normal state image right]

When I click on the image, I can animate the template of my button with a Storyboard to grow as much as I want as a result like this:

[image]

That would be the result more or less. The animation looks like this:

```
 <Storyboard x:Key="ExpandPanelRight">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandablePanel"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
        BeginTime="0:0:0"
        From="0" To="450" Duration="0:0:0.5"></DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

As you can see, no problem while growing the grid from left to right, but what I really want is the opposite: expand the Grid from right to left:

[image]

How will it be?? I can't find the answer.

Comment: Don't think that the solution is in your animation but in your grid layout. Somewhere HorizontalAlignment="Right" has to come into play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to align your bin `Image` to the right edge of your `ExpandablePanel`. Once you have done that then the `Image` will stick to the right hand side as the `Width` of the `Panel` increases. your `Storyboard` and `DoubleAnimation` code can remain the same. Your code should look something like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Blue">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="Expanding...." VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Image Source="Images/Bin.png" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: It can be the solution, but mine is not an `Expander`,  it's a Grid with some elements... Do you recommend to use `Expanders` instead of `Grid` for this?

Comment: There is no need to use an `Expander` control. The `Width` of any control can be animated. *If* you were using the above code, you could animate the `Border.Width` just as easily.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly! Thx!!